# Intranet no login on Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an Intranet based on Windows 2003 Server /SQL Server 2008 /:
The intranet is working fine on window 7/XP browsers: i enter the adress , press enter and appeard a dialog box asking the user and password to login.
But when  i try to open the same adress is not posible login , i have try with this line

```
http://afpenaserver.dyndns.org/?user:password
```

works in windows.How i must to configure Safari or something, the INtraNET are writed in ASP

```
https://afpenaserver.dyndns.org/?user:password
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to encode credentials into a URL (from loading your servers address this appears to be what you want) the correct format is;

```
http://user:password@domain.com
```

If this solves your issue, I would edit your post to hide your domain to stop your server getting hammered.